# Laravel cron acting strange

Tags: laravel, cron

I have a webshop that gets a daily import from csv files from a software program.

Daily a cronjob executes the files and empties the folder.

When I manually add the files they stay in de temp folder as they should. If the files get uploaded by the software the temp folder gets emptied and the cron job can't be executed.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

```
$schedule->call(function() {
    $files = array_sort(File::allFiles('storage/temp'));

    foreach($files as $file) {
        // doing the updating of the database
    }

    File::cleanDirectory('storage/temp');
    File::cleanDirectory('storage/images/foto');
})->dailyAt('21:15');
```

Just to be clear, the files are removed when the software executes an export. Even if that export takes place at 1pm. Cron isn't executed but files are deleted.

I manually added the files to see if the cron itself works and the files stay in the folder but at 21:15 the cron isn't executed.

Comment: we might give you some hints if you want to provide the code of your cron job. If not then I have doubts.

Comment: I can't sent the complete code becouse it's to long but I will share the most important parts